# I'm working with react_native_mqtt and need to implement secure mqtt communication between client and sever

Tags: ssl, websocket, mqtt, certificate-pinning, react-native-mqtt

While connecting to the mqtt server I'm setting useSSL to true.
443 port is being used.

I need to use SSL pinning with this call, is setting useSSL flag enough?

If not then suggest me the way in which I can use SSL pinning to securely connect with the server.

I didn't fine anything related to certificate pinning in the react_native_mqtt library.

Also, one of the libraries suggested to connect using node's tls.connect(). If anyone have used this ever please share.

Thanks

Comment: hi , have you found a response ?

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem, what I did was I added addition field to connect
`client.connect({ onSuccess: onConnect, useSSL: true ,userName:"brokerUsername", password:"brokerPassword" })`
and it worked for me.

Comment: Your solution does not work for me